# Fitting a scikits.learn.hmm.GaussianHMM to variable length training sequences

Tags: python, scikits, hidden-markov-models, scikit-learn

I'd like to fit a scikits.learn.hmm.GaussianHMM to training sequences of different length. The fit method, however, prevents using sequences of different length by doing

```
obs = np.asanyarray(obs)
```

which only works on a list of equally shaped arrays. 
Does anyone have a hint on how to proceed?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is only one of the issues of the HMM in scikit-learn; it's also lacks numerical stability. There has talk on the mailing list of perhaps dropping it not too long ago.

Answer (score 7):

You may do re-sampling to "reshape" a given input to the desired length.

Comment: Not sure why this hasn't been upvoted. +1 for the easiest solution?